# WebService (asmx) in C# with return erro code 404

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm doing maintenance on a C # project, which has WebServices. I created a new service and ran the program, it works as images below, but when calling the method for the button appears the 404 error.

And I have other similar codes that work and can not find the error in this project.

#### Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ServicosMegasul
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

#### Images

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A 404 could be a number of different things.  I would post your client-side code or whatever is calling the service.

Comment: @Ageonix The client call in this case is the browser itself. Making a test case, the service works.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting service from url and invoking the methods is different thing. The error you mention is in another language which I can not understand but have you tried adding bindings to web.congfig file?

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```